# Wicket: can I safely ignore serializable warnings?

Tags: java, serialization, wicket

Almost all of the Wicket components need a line like this

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

And sometimes there are too many those distracting lines... In which cases we can safely ignore serializable warnings? For example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CheckOut extends WebPage {
    //private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public CheckOut() {
        ...

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<Cheese> item) {
        //private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are needed only if you want to support persistent sessions [1].
You can ignore them otherwise.

1. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Persistence_Across_Restarts

Comment: Does it also apply to models (domains objects)?

Comment: Yes. Read more about serialVersionUID. It is used by the deserialization process to check whether the class has changed in the meantime. This could happen after a redeploy of the application and activated session persistence.